# Problem with Nulls and an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Value = a.Value * b.AnotherValue
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b
WHERE (Condition is true);
```

Here is the problem. The Value field for TableA does not allow nulls. If the calculation of a.Value * b.AnotherValue yields a null, an error is thrown. Now the question. Is there any way to tell the UPDATE to ignore the SET phase when the result of the calculation is a null and delete the record rather than updating it. This UPDATE is intended to update hundreds of records at a time but will fail if a single null is encountered. Also, please note that using the ISNULL() function and setting the Value to zero is not acceptable. I would like the record to be dropped if a null is encountered. Many thanks in advance for any help rendered.

Comment: Your INNER JOIN statement has no "ON" clause.  I assume it's left out for the sake of clarity :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean leave the value unchanged when nulls are encountered by "I would like the record to be dropped if a null is encountered."

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Value = isnull(a.Value * b.AnotherValue, a.value)
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b
WHERE (Condition is true);
```

If you actually want to delete the rows and are using SQL 2008 or later, try the merge statement.

```
MERGE TableA AS target 
USING TableB as source ON (target.ID = Source.ID)
WHEN MATCHED AND TableB.AnotherValue Is Null THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.Value = Target.Value * Source.AnotherValue;
```

Comment: +1 Learned something new today. (Using `MERGE` to `delete`) However your `MERGE` statement has a couple of problems: 1) `TableA` is aliased to `Target`, but then `TableA` is used later in multipart identifiers (`TableA.Id`) `TableB` is not aliased, but then later `Source.AnotherValue` is used instead of `TableB.AnotherValue`

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete rows during an update, you would need two statements: a delete followed by an update.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply in two statements:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Value = a.Value * b.AnotherValue
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b
WHERE (Condition is true) and (a.Value * b.AnotherValue) is not null;

Delete a FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b
WHERE (Condition is true) and (a.Value * b.AnotherValue) is null;
```

This is the simplest solution.

You can start doing more complex things (transactions, temp tables, `MERGE`, etc.) if the situation is not fully resolved.